# SubQuery inner join with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (REPORTDETAILS, REPORTITEMS), I want to query one of them to find a max value + 1 between two values, but I also want to find the max value + 1 of another table at the same time.

I am getting the correct value from the first table, but the second value is incorrect because of the condition that I have built in for the first table.

What is the correct way to right this statement?

Thanks for your help as always.

Here is my statement.

```
SELECT MAX(rd.REPNUMBER) + 1 as REPNUMBER, 
       MAX(ri.REPITEM) + 1 as REPITEM 

FROM  REPORTDETAILS rd INNER JOIN REPORTITEMS ri ON rd.REPNUMBER = ri.REPNUMBER  
WHERE rd.REPNUMBER BETWEEN 11000000 and 11099999;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `CASE` within your `MAX` statement and remove your WHERE `criteria`:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rd.REPNUMBER BETWEEN 11000000 and 11099999 
           THEN rd.REPNUMBER END) + 1 as REPNUMBER, 
       MAX(ri.REPITEM) + 1 as REPITEM 
FROM  REPORTDETAILS rd 
       INNER JOIN REPORTITEMS ri ON rd.REPNUMBER = ri.REPNUMBER
```

Because of the `INNER JOIN`, this would still only show the `max(repitem)` based on the matching records between `reportdetails` and `reportitems`.  If you just want the `max(repitem)` regardless of the `reportdetails`, then you could use a `CROSS JOIN` instead.

Comment: Thanks sgeddes, that works a treat.  Could you give me an example how the cross join would work?

Comment: Don't worry I will figure it out ;-)  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ullevi83 -- You're welcome, glad it worked.  If you need the `cross join` instead, that means you want the `max(repitem)` regardless of whether or not there is a matching record in the reportdetails table.  Something like `SELECT ... FROM ReportDetails rd CROSS JOIN ReportItems RI`...